# Was Ted Levin playing Bill Primm an easter egg?

Tags: reference, ray-donovan

In Ray Donovan S3E1, We see Micky (Chip) is now in Primm (State line) where he works at Buffalo Bill's casino which sets to stage for events to come.

When the rich guy pulls up to the gas pump, we see a video play at the pump, with Ted Levin playing Bill Primm, standing in front of the Buffalo Bill's casino sign.

Ted Levin played Jame Gumb in *Silence of the Lambs* (1991), better known as the infamous "Buffalo Bill".

Was this an easter egg or just a coincidence?

Comment: I admit I don't have proof either way, but it does seem unlikely to be a coincidence.